# Ignore seconds portion of TIMESTAMP field in query selection WHERE clause

Tags: timestamp, db2, seconds

Sample data:

2018-12-12 10:59:59.892

How do I query the above data and ignore the ":59.892" portion.

Reason:  If a user enters 10:59 search parameter, I want records from 10:59:00 - 10:59:59 returned.

Comment: Which Db2 version and platform?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [BETWEEN predicate](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=predicates-between-predicate). It is the equivalent of what you provided in your question: Records between timestamp with 10:59:00 to timestamp with 10:59:59.

You could also check the date first AND then the time of the value. Or you subtract your expected timestamp (2018-12-12 10:59:00) from the timestamps in question and it needs to be less than 1 MINUTE. Many options... Go with BETWEEN for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

an other simple way is to use [`TRUNC_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-trunc-timestamp) like that

```
where TRUNC_TIMESTAMP(yourtimestamp, 'MI') = timestamp '2018-12-12 10:59:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is an index on mytab (ts):

```
with 
  mytab (ts) as
(
  values
    '2018-12-12-10.59.59.892'::timestamp(12)
  , '2018-12-12-11.00.00.000'::timestamp(12)
  , '2018-12-12-11.00.00.000'::timestamp(12) - 0.000000000001 second
)
, userinput (ts) as
(
  values
    '2018-12-12-10.59.00'::timestamp
)
select t.ts
from mytab t
join userinput u on
      t.ts >= u.ts
  and t.ts < u.ts + 1 minute
```

| TS |
| --- |
| 2018-12-12 10:59:59.892000000000 |
| 2018-12-12 10:59:59.999999999999 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kmCnsiRb)

Comment: There is no index on that field.

Comment: It's easier to use the @nfgl's solution with `TRUNC_TIMESTAMP` then.